# Angular calling API Multiple time and creating a Result Table

Tags: angular, angular12

Im working on an Angular Project, We have 2 APIs.

First GET API lists, all the student details (name, admission_no, class etc..) and the other displays one student details (fee_payment, payment_amount etc..) on POST API call with student admission_no.

I want to know how can we create a table of students from these two apis ?
ie. If there are 10 students from Get API, We have call POST API 10 times with student admission_no, and create a table of students.

Comment: you can do a `forkJoin`. But it this is bad API design. Best thing is to rewrite the API

Answer (score 0):

why are you don't connect 2 data with admission_no and just return all you need on 1 api

```json
{
  name: 'abc',
  class: 'qerqwr',
  adminssion_no: '123',
  detail: {
     fee_payment: '...',
     ...
  }
}
```